# find copy of object in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Hi guys I have am array of objects, and I want to find an object that matches another object, the problem is that I have an array of objects in the object and I don't want to compare it directly because there is one object attribute that doesn't matter
here is a sample object:

```
[{
    name: 'name',
    price: 50,
    amount: 1,
    products: [{
        amount: 1,
        variant: 'first variant',
        name: 'product one'
      },
      {
        amount: 3,
        variant: 'first variant',
        name: 'product two'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: 'second name',
    price: 30,
    amount: 1,
    products: [{
        amount: 1,
        variant: 'first variant',
        name: 'product three'
      },
      {
        amount: 3,
        variant: 'first variant',
        name: 'product two'
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

And here is the second object:

```
{
  name: 'second name',
  price: 30,
  amount: 1,
  products: [{
      amount: 1,
      variant: 'first variant',
      name: 'product three'
    },
    {
      amount: 3,
      variant: 'first variant',
      name: 'product two'
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to check if the first array contains the exact object minus the amounts on the product objects, how can I check this and get the object instance returned?

Comment: So the `variant` and `name` in the `products` arrays should also match, but not the `amount`? Can the order of the `products` array be different?

Comment: Thus the OP does not want to find an object's copy or does not want to compare objects directly to one another but actually wants to find matching sub types or matching sub sets of properties.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an  unusual but working solution in which I transform the objects in strings, eliminate the `amount` property in objects inside `products` array and compare them.

```js
const arrayOfObjects = [{
    name: 'name',
    price: 50,
    amount: 1,
    products: [{
        amount: 1,
        variant: 'first variant',
        name: 'product one'
      },
      {
        amount: 3,
        variant: 'first variant',
        name: 'product two'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: 'second name',
    price: 30,
    amount: 1,
    products: [{
        amount: 1,
        variant: 'first variant',
        name: 'product three'
      },
      {
        amount: 3,
        variant: 'first variant',
        name: 'product two'
      }
    ]
  }
]

const objToBeFound = {
  name: 'second name',
  price: 30,
  amount: 1,
  products: [{
      amount: 1,
      variant: 'first variant',
      name: 'product three'
    },
    {
      amount: 3,
      variant: 'first variant',
      name: 'product two'
    }
  ]
}

const match = arrayOfObjects.find((obj) => JSON.stringify(obj).replaceAll(/{\"amount\":\d+,/g, '{') === JSON.stringify(objToBeFound).replace(/{\"amount\":\d+,/g, '{'));

console.log(match)
```

Comment: Are you aware, that one can not rely on key order for the *stringify* approach, especially not, since one does not know how the object structures of each list are created.